# My jar file won't load images

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, imageicon

I am currently writing a program that I need to send to a friend as a jar. The program has images that need to be loaded for the program to work properly and I want it all to be contained in the one jar. Currently it doesn't work from the executable jar or when I run it through command line. It works in netbeans however.

Here's the code I'm using:

To load the image I'm using:

```
protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path, String description)
{
 java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path);
 if (imgURL != null)
 {
     return new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                  .getImage(imgURL),description);
 }
 else
 {
     System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
     return null;
 }
}
```

for the URL I've also tried just

```
 getClass().getResource(path)
```

The line where the image is supposed to be created is:

```
this.img =createImageIcon(File.separator+"."+File.separator
           +"resources"+File.separator+"tiles"+File.separator+"tile.png","tile");
```

My jar file is setup with the folder containing the class files and the resource folder both on the top level of it.

I have searched around for ways to resolve this, but I cannot find anything that works.

Thanks.

Comment: On your "createImageIcon" function are you passing in the filename of where the image is going to be created? Because if this is the case it means the file is being saved to /./resources/tiles/tile.png" which equates to "/resources/tiles/tile.png" which would be at the root level of the file system. In this case it wouldn't be found by your classpath once you deploy it.

Comment: how about using / instead of File.separator and having "/resources/titles/tile.png" instead of "/./resources/titles/tile.png" which can be an incorrect path depending on the system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL will evaluate to `"/./resources/tiles/tile.png"` which does not make sense (but maybe the `ClassLoader` that is used when you run from NetBeans tolerates the error.)
Try dropping the initial `"/./"`. Also you do not need the references to `File.separator` as the string is treated as a relative URL and the forward slash is always valid.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `/./resources/back_img.png`, use `resources/back_img.png` with `ClassLoader`.
Here is example :

```
    String path = "resources/back_img.png";
    ClassLoader cl = ImageHandler.class.getClassLoader();
    URL imgURL = cl.getResource(path);
    //URL imgURL = ImageHandler.class.getResource(path);

    if (imgURL != null) {
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
        Image img = icon.getImage();
        Image sizedImg = img.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        return new ImageIcon(sizedImg);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite anything else your code has the unenviable property of being fail-slow.

Try something like

```
URL x = get class.getclassloader.getresource(...)
If x == null
   Throw new defect "expected ... But it wasn't there"
```

Sorry for the formatting, but the iPad makes it too hard to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue in Intellij Idea by declaring my Background folder(which was containing the images) as Resource folder in project structure settings. In Intellij project structure can be accessed from **File->Project Structure** or with shortcut **ctrl+shift+alt+S**, inside that you can go to modules to configure the roles of all the folders in the project. I believe Netbeans might have similar feature.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).