# Within resources in JAR

Tags: java, image, jar

We have a Jar-file. There are 3 folders:

1-st: **META-INF**

2-nd: **resources**

3-rd: **classes**

How can a class from folder **classes** get **image** from folder **resources**?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you at least tried a simple google search for "java resources jar"? there seem to be lots of examples out there...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675617/my-jar-file-wont-load-images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
String path = "resources/something.png";
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path));
```

To do it in a static context, like in a static initializer block:

```
String path = "resources/something.png";
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(className.class.getClassLoader().getResource(path));
```

Comment: If you use the path="/resources/something.png" you can omit the getClassLoader() and just call className.class.getResource(path).

Comment: A lot of THankS!!!  And can we write something in file MANIFEST.MF to point at a folder of any resources?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [ClassLoader.getResource](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) or [getResourceAsStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), both of which will allow you to read files stored within your JAR. You can access the class loader with `YourClass.class.getClassLoader()`. See this question for more details: [Load a resource contained in a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574809/java-load-a-resource-contained-in-a-jar)